# Need to add URL patterns to include in JMeter for Specific URL Substring

Tags: url, testing, jmeter

I need to Record Only URLS having "jobs/csuser__csuser__eam2__search" in the Entire network request. Please Let me know how can I fulfill the same with the

URL Patterns to include Option of Jmeter in "HTTP(S) Test SCript Recorder"

...../csuser/eam2/search/**jobs/csuser__csuser__eam2__search**1_1413442824.2983
...../csuser/eam2/search/**jobs/csuser__csuser__eam2__search**1_1413442824.2983/results_preview

...../csuser/eam2/search/**jobs/csuser__csuser__eam2__search**2_1413442824.2993
...../csuser/eam2/search/**jobs/csuser__csuser__eam2__search**2_1413442824.1983/results_preview
.
.

...../csuser/eam2/search/**jobs/csuser__csuser__eam2__search**N_1423442824.2983
...../csuser/eam2/search/**jobs/csuser__csuser__eam2__search**N_1423442884.2983/results_preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **".*csuser__csuser__eam2__search.*"** to **"URL patterns to include"** in "HTTP(S) Test SCript Recorder"

Hope this will help